# create new instance with new Class() and optionally assign properties

Tags: typescript, class, constructor

I want a class which I can create a new instance from and optionally assign properties to with the constructor.

For example:

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  constructor(props: {name?: string, age?: number}) {
    this.name = props?.name?? "";
    this.age = props?.age?? 0;
  }
}

const person1 = new Person({name:"Pete"})
```

Is there a more elegant way than this?

Comment: Btw, `this.age = props?.name ?? 0;` should be `this.age = props?.age ?? 0;`; though `age` needs to be optional in `props`

Answer (score 0):

If "elegant" means [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) syntax, then there's not much to improve upon. As in the example below, you could remove syntax from the constructor body implementation by using [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) and a self-referential type modified by the [`Partial<Type>` utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGtMA5vAFzRoCuAtgEZIDcuZYlJ0EALogJZoEOPB0HROWDsUiABSZ8RaAF5oABgA0TFgugAiLdAC+pWGETsuYEAB4EydAD5NmPQEosjPOwAWXCADpC8TX8GPHcvXzRmAMUIlmD9bD1sbEE0VBB4HxAUAkk0eAB3OCRUNGl1Vi0EdnhdZyc6aAB6RqxZVlVy0kr4atrkoRR0zOzcgqKbUpl-UgBGAFY5-Sd6ppapolmFtRiKvpS0jKycvMLrErLp6Hm57ciuqpqllebWy+vblnuex8T9wcORidxudHMsGi91u0Prt4n8hkdRqdiuhJGDVq8NspoV0+kA)

```ts
class Person {
  age: number;
  name: string;

  constructor({ age = 0, name = "" }: Partial<Person> = {}) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

console.log(new Person({ name: "Pete" })); // { age: 0, name: "Pete" }
console.log(new Person({ age: 155 })); // { age: 155, name: "" }
console.log(new Person({ age: 155, name: "Pete" })); // { age: 155, name: "Pete" }
console.log(new Person({})); // { age: 0, name: "" }
console.log(new Person()); // { age: 0, name: "" }
```

In my view, this just relocates syntax complexity from one location to another. TypeScript is verbose, but there's nothing necessarily wrong with that. Elegant code is code that can be easily understood by others. Being explicit helps others understand what is happening in your code.

---

TypeScript also has [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties). However, this concept doesn't apply to your example because the single constructor parameter is an object type, which can't be assigned to any members of the class itself. If you refactored your class constructor to use ordered parameters for each of its fields (instead of an object parameter), then you could use this syntax pattern.